# how to have a property setter for a nd-array or matrix in python?

Tags: python-3.x, properties

I am not sure how can I achieve setting a nd array/matrix in the following syntactic way instead of complicated workaround. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

for example:

```
import numpy as np

class myExample:
    def __init__(self):
        self._matrix = np.empty([2,2])

    @property
    def matrix(self, row_id=None, col_id=None):
        if row_id == None or col_id == None:
            return self._matrix
        else:
            return self._matrix[row_id, col_id]

    @matrix.setter
    def matrix(self, row_id, col_id, new_val):
        print("{}{}".format(row_id, col_id)
        self._matrix[row_id, col_id] = new_val

Test = myExample()
Test.matrix[1,2] = 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

why not [inherit from `np.array`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.11.0/user/basics.subclassing.html#basics-subclassing)?

```
import numpy as np

class myExample(np.ndarray):
    def __new__(cls):
        zero = np.zeros((2, 4), dtype=np.int)
        obj = np.asarray(zero).view(cls)
        return obj

Test = myExample()
Test[1,2] = 3
print(Test)
```

that way you get the getters and setters ([`__getitem__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__)/`__setitem__`) for free.

(note that your index `[1, 2]` is out of bounds for your shape `[2, 2]`).

---

and your example actually works if you just have a `getter`; you return an `np.array` that already has the needed properties:

```
import numpy as np

class myExample:
    def __init__(self):
        self._matrix = np.empty([3, 4])

    @property
    def matrix(self):
        return self._matrix


Test = myExample()
Test.matrix[1,2] = 3
```

---

update after OP's comments: if you need to print your matrix (or do other things) before setting the items you could try this:

```
import numpy as np

class myExample:
    def __init__(self):
        self._matrix = np.zeros([3, 4])

    @property
    def matrix(self):
        return self._matrix

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print(self._matrix)  # or other things...
        self._matrix[key] = value

Test = myExample()
Test[1, 3] = 5
```

Comment: I was going to answer with creating a wrapper class with `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` which has whatever else you want in it, but this answer is even better, although you lose control over what you want it to do, it's sometimes better to create your own class when you want to have a flat array, but 2D indexed, unless numpy arrays already are like that, which doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: I can't inherit as this is a much simplified example for illustration purposes. Actual class is much more complex and nd-array is only one of the attributes amongst few dozen others.

Comment: what about the second suggestion then?

Comment: Second suggestion is ok but i run into following issues - (a) In my custom matrix setter, i would have liked to do more things before setting. Here i have illustrated that with print statement as example (b) I will not be able to set entire matrix as $$ Test.matrix = np.zeros([2,2]) $$ since it doesn't have setter